# Erro ao enviar ArrayList via POST no Retrofit 2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: android, json, web-service, gson, retrofit

Quando tento enviar um ArrayList via @POST para ser salvo no meu webserver com o Retrofit2, o ArrayList é salvo, porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

O que posso fazer para resolver este erro?
Acho que tem alguma coisa a ver com o Gson, porém sou iniciante no assunto e estou meio perdido.

Este é o ArrayList que estou tentando enviar:

```
ArrayList<ModelContato> listContatos = new ArrayList<>();

    ModelContato c = new ModelContato("5", "ATIVO", "TESTE", "12134567", "14646", "email@email.com", "Teste");
    listContatos.add(c);
    c = new ModelContato("6", "INATIVO", "TESTE2", "12123456", "14646", "email@email.com", "Teste2");
    listContatos.add(c);
```

E esta é a minha Call que realiza o envio:

```
Call<List<ModelContato>> callM = contatoInterface.createRContato(listContatos);
    callM.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelContato>>() {
        @Override

    public void onResponse(Response<List<ModelContato>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Salvo com sucesso");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Erro ao salvar: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Esta é a minha interface:

```
public interface ContatoInterface {

@GET("recebe")
Call<List<ModelContato>> getRContatos();

@POST("envia")
Call<List<ModelContato>> createRContato(@Body ArrayList<ModelContato> modelContato);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifique o retorno que você deseja receber em sua interface.
Temos:

```
@POST("envia")
Call<List<ModelContato>> createRContato(@Body ArrayList<ModelContato> modelContato);}
```

Isso significa que após realizar o post você espera receber do servidor uma Lista. Porém, você está recebendo uma string como diz o erro que você obteve.

Então basta verificar o que você esta enviando de volta como resposta ao criar o usuário e modificar sua interface, creio eu que o seguinte deva resolver:

```
 @POST("envia")
    Call<String> createRContato(@Body ArrayList<ModelContato> modelContato);}
```